# Error in IIF Statement of Query within TableAdapter

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, dataset

Hi and sorry for poor english

i have 3 tables in a access database with .mdb format -
i am using this database in vs 2010 as a data source. I Have a TableAdapter with the following fill Query (Connection is MS Jet 4.0) :

```
 SELECT        a.ID AS AmelID, a.NamAmel, a.MoshtariRef, a.ShHesab, a.Kod, a.NamF, a.NamSM, derivedtbl_1.MablaghKol, derivedtbl_1.Cnt, iif(derivedtbl_2.MablaghKolBrg is Null, 0,derivedtbl_2.MablaghKolBrg) As MablaghKolBrg, iif(derivedtbl_2.CntKolBrg is Null, 0,derivedtbl_2.CntKolBrg) As CntBrg,
iif(derivedtbl_3.MablaghKolVsl is Null, 0,derivedtbl_3.MablaghKolVsl) As MablaghKolVsl,iif(derivedtbl_3.CntVsl is Null, 0,derivedtbl_3.CntVsl) As CntVsl 
FROM            ((((SELECT        Amel.ID, Amel.NamAmel, Chek.MoshtariRef, Chek.ShHesab, Moshtari.Kod, Moshtari.NamF, Moshtari.NamSM
                                FROM            ((Amel INNER JOIN
                                                         Chek ON Amel.ID = Chek.ID) INNER JOIN
                                                         Moshtari ON Amel.ID = Moshtari.AmelRef)
                                GROUP BY Amel.ID, Amel.NamAmel, Chek.MoshtariRef, Chek.ShHesab, Moshtari.Kod, Moshtari.NamF, Moshtari.NamSM) a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        SUM(Mablagh) AS MablaghKolVsl, COUNT(Mablagh) AS CntVsl, MoshtariRef, ShHesab
                                FROM            Chek Chek_3
                                WHERE        (Status = '1')
                                GROUP BY MoshtariRef, ShHesab) derivedtbl_3 ON a.MoshtariRef = derivedtbl_3.MoshtariRef AND a.ShHesab = derivedtbl_3.ShHesab) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        SUM(Mablagh) AS MablaghKol, COUNT(Mablagh) AS Cnt, MoshtariRef, ShHesab
                                FROM            Chek Chek_1
                                GROUP BY MoshtariRef, ShHesab) derivedtbl_1 ON a.MoshtariRef = derivedtbl_1.MoshtariRef AND a.ShHesab = derivedtbl_1.ShHesab) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        SUM(Mablagh) AS MablaghKolBrg, COUNT(Mablagh) AS CntKolBrg, MoshtariRef, ShHesab
                                FROM            Chek Chek_2
                                WHERE        (Status = '2')
                                GROUP BY MoshtariRef, ShHesab) derivedtbl_2 ON a.ShHesab = derivedtbl_2.ShHesab AND a.MoshtariRef = derivedtbl_2.MoshtariRef)
```

to avoid getting Null values i have created an IIF statement in 4 last columns which works fine in access but in vs table adapter gives the following error :

```
Error in list of function arguments: 'IS' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.
```

in the same time i see the results with 0 instead of nulls which means the IIF statement works fine.

but i need the table adapter to fill tables which doesnt happen because of the error.
what should i do ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :D

just create columns in table manually. it will work whether you use it in datagrid or reports. just make sure column names in query match the column names in table.